# simpledateformat getting parsing exceptiong using java

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

My input is `2014-12-12T10:39:40Z`. I want output like `12//11/2014 8:58:15 AM`. 
here i am using

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy'T' HH:mm:ss 'a'");
```

But i am geting parsing exception.
let me know how to write simpledateformat.

Advance Thanks
Srinivas B

Comment: Post the snippet, parse from and parse true. I think you are mixing the two.

Comment: Can you write exactly the exception are you getting?

Comment: Lemme know what is the input type . Is Date or String.

Comment: Please add some more code of what you have tried.

Comment: Check out the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for Date and Time patterns.

Comment: The pattern you're using, which we don't know if it's used to parse your input, or generate your output, doesn't match any of your dates.

Answer (score 1):

you need two `DateFormatter` one to match your input pattern then second one to format it in the format you need, You are parsing input with your  output  `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 1):

If your input date is a `String`, then first you need to parse that to convert to a `Date`.
You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` object for that.

Then, to output in the format you want,
you need another `SimpleDateFormat` object.

Something like this:

```
    String input = "2014-12-12T10:39:40Z";
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    Date date = parser.parse(input);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss a");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're input appears to be ISO8601, so you can use DatatypeConverter. There are issues parsing 8601 dates using SimpleDateFormat, see [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

```
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd/MM/yyyy'T' HH:mm:ss 'a'");
Date input = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(
        "2014-12-12T10:39:40Z").getTime();

System.out.println(output.format(input));
```

Java 8 using new time API

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2014-12-12T10:39:40Z",
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);

Date utilDate =  Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
System.out.println(output.format(utilDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy'T' HH:mm:ss a");
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");

System.out.println(formatter.format(formatter1.parse("2014-12-12T10:39:40'a'")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String input = "2014-12-12T10:39:40Z";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Date date = parser.parse(input);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```